# Error in cfBuild(X_reduced, y, ensNum = 2, bootNum = 100, seed = 1) : could not find function "cfBuild"

Tags: r, machine-learning, pca, rlang

I have imported the library classyfireR which has the cfBuild function but when I try to use the function in code it is giving me an error.Also I tried importing classyfire in R but it shows this error "Warning in install.packages :
package ‘classyfire’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at"

```
library(R.matlab)
library(classyfireR)
library(magrittr)


bgw <- readMat("BWG_FA_CDvCTRL.mat")

X <- bgw$XTIC
y <- bgw$CLASS
X
y
rownames(X) <- as.character(unlist(bgw$SAM))
# Summary of the dataset
summary(bgw)
# table 
table(bgw)
# dim
dim(bgw)

RT <- bgw$RT

i = 1 # set index number to sample you want to plot 
plot(RT, X[i,], type="l", xlab="RT (min)", ylab="Intensity",
     main=sprintf("TIC profile for sample: %s", rownames(X)[i]))



# Preprocessing data using PCA 
# Scaling the data
X <- scale(X)

# PCA
# Principal component analysis reduces the dimensionality of the data
pca <- prcomp(X)

# get the eigenvalues
pca$sdev

# get the eigenvectors
pca$rotation

# get the loadings
pca$xload

# get the scores
pca$xscores

X_reduced <- pca$xscores[,1:2]

model <- cfBuild(X_reduced, y, ensNum=2, bootNum=100, seed=1)
```

Comment: What R version are you using? Your actual issue seems to be that you can't install this package.

Comment: Hi Roland! I am using R 4.2.0 which is mentioned on a console in R studio (macOS)

Comment: Are you referring to this package? https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/classyfireR/classyfireR.pdf There is no "cfBuild" function within it.